# Azure logic app - how to iterate over json?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a json file that looks like this:

```
{
    "first key": "some url",
    "second key": "some other url",
    "third key": "yet another url",
        ...
}
```

I want to make a  azure logic app that sends an http request (with the same body) to each of those urls. What i need to do is to iterate over urls, but i have no idea how to do so since it is not an array. For now all i have is getting the json file from blob storage and parsing it inside logic app to get shown output.

One more thing worth mentioning is that this json may have more or less keys, this number varies. Sometimes it will consist of 5 urls, sometimes 2.
Also names: "first key", "second key", "third key" are not important here and will not be accessed anywhere in logic app if that helps. All i can assume is that those will be unique strings.

Tried all options of "for each" block, but all i have achieved is accessing specific url by providing specific key.

Comment: Correct, you can’t loop over it because it’s not an array. Question, are the names of the properties literally as you provided? i.e. “link1”, “link2”, “link3”, etc?

Comment: Thats a good point @Skin, unfortunately they are not all this way :( updated the question

Comment: I have a way for you to do it.  A custom connector my company built has an operation but it's not yet productionised to the connector, it can be accessed via a HTTP request though.  More doco can be found here ... https://www.statesolutions.com.au/json-properties-to-name-value-pair-array/ ... it will be in the `Advanced Data Operations` connector within the coming few weeks but again, you can call it now via the HTTP action.  If you want to know more, contact us via the relevant support page or simply sign up for a trial.

Comment: That operation will turn the object into an array so you can iterate over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can hold out, there is an operation coming in the `Advanced Data Operations` connector which is due to drop in preview sometime in **Feb, 2023**.

[image: Flow]

The above operation will produce the following result ...

```
[
  {
    "propertyName": "first key",
    "propertyType": "String",
    "propertyValue": "some url"
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "second key",
    "propertyType": "String",
    "propertyValue": "some other url"
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "third key",
    "propertyType": "String",
    "propertyValue": "yet another url"
  }
]
```

This will allow you to iterate over the object and pull each value (along with the property name if required) as you desire.

If you can't hold out, the operation is available via the HTTP connector, you just need to read the documentation on how to structure the JSON for the call.

https://www.statesolutions.com.au/json-properties-to-name-value-pair-array/

Comment: That's great news! I can postpone it till this feature release. Thanks!

Comment: @RadosławGdula this is currently being deployed around the world so if you check, depending on the region your LogicApp is deployed in, it will be available either now or by the 28th of Feb, that's when the global deployment will be complete.

Answer (score 0):

Issue reproduced from my end follow these steps.
Add compose action and form array with http body. Based on http request body you need to add urls dynamically. I have done as shown below,

1. Created logic app as shown below,
   [image]
2. In http request sending body as shown below,

{

“link1”: “some url”,

“link2”: “some other url”,

“link3”: "yet another url

}

[image]
3. In compose action, forming array with http body as shown below,

[image]

4. Next taken for each loop and passing outputs of compose action as input,

[image]

In this way it will iterate over each url of the Http body request.
logic App ran successfully as shown below.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am a bit worried if this will work if i get more than 3 links? What if the json will consist of 4? As i mentioned this number will vary and i cant really predict how many items there will be and what the keys will look like. Updated the question to make it clear